# Pervasive URL rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hey guys I have a URL rewrite below that works, unfortunately when using pagination the SEO portion of my url comes back and is not forced into a 301

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/html_sitemap/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/catalog/seo_sitemap/$1 [L,NC,P]
```

I tried the below code, but it was unsuccessful, what am I missing?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^catalog/seo_sitemap/(.*)$
RewriteRule http://%{HTTP_HOST}/catalog/html_sitemap/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Missing to state the question clearly, for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/html_sitemap/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/catalog/seo_sitemap/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Due to the fact that `catalog/html_sitemap/` does not actually exist though, only `catalog/seo_sitemap/` does, I end up in a 404 page. Very close though!

Comment: Yes, but in this case why did you invert my answer ? Because I do that.